# How to make the SearchList work by String in Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

i have a searchview with a listview. i put some items to open a new activity. While im in the first Activity, all right. But if i search another item on Searchview, app obeys the position. Then, wrong item is chosen.
How can i make the item click work by String?

My code:

```js
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    ListView lv;
    SearchView sv;
    String[] teams={"Activity 1","Activity 2","Activity 3","Activity 4","Activity 5","Activity 6"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv=(ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        sv=(SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,teams);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
                        adapter.getFilter().filter(text);
                        return false;
                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    //to open new activity
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        if (position == 0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (position == 1) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } 
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can i make the item click work by String?

```
    @Override
    //to open new activity
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String team = teams[position];
        if (team.equalsIgnoreCase("Activity 1")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (team.equalsIgnoreCase("Activity 2")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } //...and so on
        }
    }
```